# New to ROS as well as LINUX

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,
This is Shailendra singh from India.I am very new to ROS+LINUX.Till now i was working with windows,embedded system and simple manual robotics using AVR series 8 bit micrcontrollers.But to get myself updated according to the latest trends of RObotics,i started learning ROS.I started with installing ubuntu10.10.Then i installed ROS using command $ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop.this installed ros of 728 mb in my system.Than i started working with the help of [https://wiki.nps.edu/display/~thchung/Setting+Up+a+Clean+Installation+of+ROS](https://wiki.nps.edu/display/%7Ethchung/Setting+Up+a+Clean+Installation+of+ROS) but i find that i am not getting anything.Is there any tutorial availiable with the help of which i can start step by step.I know i am asking very silly question,but need help in that.Its quite confusing.
i) I understand the use of ROS,its basically used to simulate robots rather than testing them in real time.
ii) Wheres the coding part?
iii) And how should we start?

if someone can give those answers i think it will be too great for new webbies to understand things too easily.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33263/new-to-ros-as-well-as-linux./) by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find everything you need to know in the form of tutorials on the official ROS site here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

I don't actually know why you started with website you mentioned on your question, but this is apparently about how to configure ROS Diamondback with the Ganzebo simulator and several other packages and NOT about how to get started with ROS. I also recommend you to install the newest ROS release Fuerte like it is explained here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-04**:
Maverick (Ubuntu 10.10) is not supported in Fuerte. If @srj0408 really wants to stick with Maverick, Electric is the newest compatible ROS distribution.

**Comment by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on 2012-05-04**:
@joq:- Well i do have electric installed to in my UBUNTU10.10.But i am not getting what to do next,because there are many confusing tutorials in that.Means after that how should i continue with simulators as obiviousaly i dont have harware to work with,what about the coding to be done for simulation

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-05-04**:
You should first go through the tutorials ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials )  to know how ROS works. After completing those, you can go to the ROS package of the Gazebo simulator and start working. Having done the tutorials, you will know how to get this started...